# Website for live testing of HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a website for pasting code HTML/JS, when you can edit HTML/JS and see changes live?

Comment: I changed the title, because I initially thought you were asking for a [Pastebin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastebin).

Comment: Is this something which could benefit from Firebug or Chrome Developer extension?

Comment: If it's just HTML and JS why not just run it from your desktop with Chrome?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is one of the best I've seen so far!
[jsbin](http://jsbin.com) a second runner up.

There are bound to be others (and this answer is Community Wiki if you want to add them)

Answer (score 2):

you could also try the Google Playground
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Tryit Editor - http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic. To see changes, just click on the 'See Result >>' button.

Answer (score 0):

Several Realtime HTML Editor

- [Scratchpad.io](http://scratchpad.io/overwrought-structure-7325)
- [onlinehtmleditor](http://www.onlinehtmleditor.net/)
- [htmlinstant](http://www.htmlinstant.com/)
- [Squarefree](http://htmledit.squarefree.com/)
- [Google list](https://www.google.co.id/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=realtime%20html%20editor&oq=realtime%20html%20editor&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4958j0j1)